# refresh a write only excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, password-protection, writeonly

I am trying to refresh an excel workbook.  There are two sheets that need to be refreshed because they are connected to our database.  The workbook is saved as a write only.  I can get the workbook to open but I can't get the password to be written and it is the correct password.  This is the code I have so far.

```
Set data = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
data.Visible = True
Set wb = data.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\tdumas\Desktop\Rental Aerial Agreement    
(TEMPLATE).xlsx", WriteResPassword="lift123456")_
ReadOnlyRecommended=False
IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended=True
data.ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
WScript.Sleep(SecondsToWait * 5000)
data.ActiveWorkbook.Save
wb.Close
data.Application.Quit
```

Comment: Does it prompt for a password if you omit `writerespassword`?

Comment: Yes it does.  No matter how I write it, it keeps prompting for the password.  Once you enter it manually then it will go through the refreshing stage.

Comment: What about `WriteResPassword:="lift123456"` with the colon?

Comment: It gives me an error saying it can not run the script, that's why I took them out.  When I take the password off of the workbook I can refresh it through script but when I put it back on is when the issue comes in play.  And we need it password protected.

Comment: What error were you getting?

Comment: Line 5, Cahr: 113, Error: Expected, Code 800A03EE

Comment: What about toggling or removing `ReadOnlyRecommended`?

Comment: I have try to remove it and still did not work.